# Eclipse Gradle multiprojects

Tags: eclipse, gradle, multi-project

I've just been through the ringer trying to get this to work so I thought i would share my experience.

The problem (so I can answer it QA style):

I have a flat project structure where the sub-projects are siblings of the root project:

```
rootProject
childProject1
childProject2
childProject3
```

In my `rootProject:settings.gradle` I used an `include`:

```
include '../childProject1', '../childProject2', '../childProject3'
```

This worked for the simple builds (no real gradle configuration had yet been performed).

Then upon `Gradle Import > Build Model` the import dialog showed:

```
[] rootProject
```

And there were no childProjects.

I did a bit of reading and had the Aha! moment when i re-read the doco and saw I actually want `includeFlat`.  So I changed it to:

```
includeFlat 'childProject1', 'childProject2', 'childProject3'
```

However it didn't work.  Grumble grumble grumble.

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around I had to do:

1. Delete these files from the project's:

   - `.project`
   - `.settings`
   - `.gradle`
2. Sometimes that wasn't enough and I had to shut down Eclipse / STS and delete the contents of the workspace directory

Then it worked and upon `build Model` of the RootProject I would see in the import dialog:

```
[] rootProject
    [] childProject1
    [] childProject2
    [] childProject3
```

Problem solved.

I've never encountered a situation like this where I had to do lots of eclipse project metadata cleanup to get functionality functioning.